# Exclude attribute in Collection

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.0.1, collection, filter

I have a multi-select product attribute and i am wanting to exclude several values from a collection.

i.e

```
attribute = filter_theme
possible values = A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
```

If i use `nin` like so:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('filter_theme', array('nin' => $exclude));
```

It will only work if the products only have a single selection on `filter_theme` i.e `value A`

If they have more than one it won't work i.e `values A & B`. (I know this is also the case when using `in` to find rather than exclude)

Again i know that i can use `finset` to find any products with $exclude, whether it has 1 or all options selected:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('filter_theme', array('finset' => $exclude));
```

This will work on both `value A` only and `value A & B & C`being selected.

Is there a way of doing the opposite of `finset` to exclude rather than include so that it works no matter how many values are selected for my attribute?

Answer (score 1):

What about using finset and manipulating your array instead?

You could do the following:

```
$possibleValues = array('A','B','C'...);
$excludeValues = array('B', 'C'...);

$includeValues = array_diff($possibleValues, $excludeValues);
```

And then you can just use your `finset` on `includeValues`